# Is there is a work around to add random elements to iterating list in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, random, increment, grasshopper

I am trying to generate 10 random points in Grasshopper and add them to a list using the following code:

```
private void RunScript(object x, object y, ref object A)
{

    List<Point3d> pts = new List<Point3d>();
    //List<Point3d> temp = new List<Point3d>();

    Point3d origin = new Point3d(20, 20, 0);
    pts.Add(origin);
    //temp.Add(origin);
    Random r = new Random();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10){
      Point3d pt_temp = new Point3d(r.Next(20, 30), r.Next(20, 30), 0);
      foreach (Point3d p in pts){
        if (p != pt_temp){
          pts.Add(pt_temp);
          i++;
        }else{
          break;
        }

      }

    }
    A = pts;

  }
```

I couldn't execute the enumeration operation. I have searched a lot, but couldn't find a solution for a similar case with adding random unique elements to an iterating list.

Comment: Your inner loop is wrong. If your `pts` list contains 3 points, and they are all different to `pt_temp` then you would add the same `pt_temp` to the list three times. So even if this code did work without the enumeration error, the logic would still be wrong. Perhaps use LINQ's `.Any` on the `pts` list?

Comment: What do you mean by "I couldn't execute the enumeration operation"? Note that the logic to search for an existing point is wrong. It will add the point multiple times if it finds multiple points that do not match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this, your code can not be compiled, because of wrong using foreach

```
    List<Point3D> pts = new List<Point3D> { new Point3D(20, 20, 0)};

    Random r = new Random();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        Point3D pt_temp = new Point3D(r.Next(20, 30), r.Next(20, 30), 0);
        if (pts.Any(p => p == pt_temp)) continue;
        pts.Add(pt_temp);
        i++;
    }
 A = pts;
```

a variant without linq

```
    List<Point3D> pts = new List<Point3D> { new Point3D(20, 20, 0) };

    Random r = new Random();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        Point3D pt_temp = new Point3D(r.Next(20, 30), r.Next(20, 30), 0);
    
        var exist = false;
        foreach (var item in pts) { if (item == pt_temp) exist = true; break; }
        if (exist) continue;

        pts.Add(pt_temp);
        i++;
    }
 A = pts;
```

Comment: Worked. only I had to use System.Linq and use structure Point3d instead of Point3D

Comment: @KarimYosefRezk I added variant without linq if you like this more. Also I didnt now what namespace for 3d

Answer (score 0):

Well, canonical way to solve such problem  is to use Set, HashSet in this particular case. Set would guarantee uniqueness of the elements

Along the lines (untested!)

```
var r = new HashSet<PointD>();
while (r.Count < 10) {
    r.Add(new Point3D(......));
}
return r;
```